# How do I modify this REGEX to pick up all dates in the test string

Tags: python, regex, date

```
test_string = '''dated as of October 17, 2012 when we went caroling, dated as of December 21, 2011 when we ate bananas'''


import re
import calendar

months_full = '|'.join([month for month in calendar.month_name][1:])

pattern_1 = r'\b' + months_full + r'\s+\d{1,2},?\s+\d{4},?'
test_pattern = re.compile(pattern_1)
x = test_pattern.findall(test_string)

print x

>>> 
['October', 'December 21, 2011']
>>>
```

I think my regex is asking

beginning at a word boundary

find any month (correctly spelled and capitalized

next require there to be one or more white spaces

followed by 1 or 2 digits

there might be one or zero commas next

followed by one or more white spaces

then there should be 4 digits

and it might end with a comma immediately adjacent to the last digit

Once I get dates I intend to validate them so I am not too worried about the case

January 1, 2999 cases of rum as if I can check to see if the date is in a valid range.

I did discover that when I replace the first month with December the regex returns both dates.  I have played around with  \b . and other variations but can't seem to get past this.

Any observations will be much appreciated

Comment: You have forgotten to put your alternation (with month names) in a non capturing group `(?:...)`

Comment: Supply that as an answer

Comment: Thanks if you give me it as an answer I can mark it accepted and useful

Comment: FYI, if you want to see what a regex is doing, you can do the following: `re.compile(pattern_1, re.DEBUG)`, and it will print out useful diagnostic information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern doesn't work because you have forgotten to put the alternation with month names in a non capturing group `(?:...)`

An other notice:

It's a shame to load a module only to have the month names in english, when you can write them and optimise your pattern! Example:

```
pattern_1 = r'\b(?:(?:jan|febr)uary|ma(?:y|rch)|ju(?:ne|ly)|a(?:pril|ugust)|(?:octo|(?:sept|nov|dec)em)ber)\s+[0-9]{1,2},?\s+[0-9]{4},?'
```

Comment: I would edit your answer but I don't have enough reputation you need another paren ((?:octo|(?:sept|nov|dec)em)ber))  Do you see?  right after ust|

Comment: The comment `I have corrected (i think)` is telling. That regex is extremely hard to read and it is unclear what is 'optimized' about it. The corrected original list comprehension is a lot easier to read and understand.

Comment: @dawg: In this case use it.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close!

Try:

```
import re
import calendar

test_string = '''dated as of October 17, 2012 when we went caroling, dated as of December 21, 2011 when we ate bananas'''
test_pattern = re.compile('|'.join(r'(?:\b%s\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4})' % month 
                                       for month in calendar.month_name[1:]))
print test_pattern.findall(test_string)
# ['October 17, 2012', 'December 21, 2011']
```

Other comments:

1. There is no need for the optional `,?` at the end of your regex. It really does not validate a date any more that the first part of the regex.
2. You may need to use the [re.I](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.I) for making case insensitive.
3. You may need to use [re.S](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S) to deal with a carriage return in a legitimate date like `December 21,\n2011`
4. Use named capture groups to capture the month, day and year and then use datetime to validate the date.